# Integral inequality $I_2(z) = \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers, integral-inequality

I want to prove the inequality of an integral like this:

$$I_2(z) = \int_1^{+\infty} \frac{\rho(t)}{(z+t)^2} d t = \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}\right)$$ , when $z \to +\infty$

Below is my current attempt：

$$\begin{aligned}
I_2(z) & =\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{\rho(t)}{(z+t)^2} d t \\
& =\frac{R(t)}{(z+t)^2}\Big|_1 ^{+\infty}+2 \int_1^{+\infty} \frac{R(t)}{(z+t)^3} d t \\
&\leq \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{|(z+1)+t|^3} d t 
\end{aligned}$$

Where，

$$\begin{gathered}
\rho(t)=\{t\}-\frac{1}{2},|\rho(t)| \leq \frac{1}{2}, \\
R(t)=\int_1^t \rho(s) d s, \quad|R(t)| \leq \frac{1}{2} .
\end{gathered}$$

The last integral with absolute value I don't know how to handle it properly.

Comment: $z \neq -1,-2,...,-n,..$ The integral is derived from series representation of digamma funtion $\psi(z+1)=-\gamma+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+z}\right) $

Comment: Sorry,I didn't make it clear, what I want to prove is: when $z \to +\infty$,$I_2(z)=\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}\right) $.In this case $Re(z) > 0$ and it can be big as it needs to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $z=x+iy$ with $x > 0$ is, as you already calculated,
$$
 I_2(z) = \int_1^\infty \frac{2R(t)}{(z+t)^3} \, dt
$$
and $|2 R(t)|\le 1$. Let us first assume that $y \ne 0$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
 |I_2(z)| &\le \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{(x+t)^2+y^2)^{3/2}} \, dt \\
 &= \left[ \frac {x+t}{y^2 \sqrt{(x+t)^2+y^2}}\right]_{t=1}^{t=\infty} \\
&= \frac{1}{y^2} \left( 1 - \frac{x+1}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2} \cdot (\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2} + (x+1))} \\
&\le \frac{1}{(x+1)^2+y^2} \\
&= \frac{1}{|z+1|^2} \, .
\end{align}
$$
By continuity it follows that the same estimates holds also if $y=0$.